# WooCommerce database user and payment check

Tags: php, database, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I have a tiny webapp that I want to sell the "access" to it. The app is developed with HTML5+CSS3+JavaScript, is hosted in the same server that I have my Wordpress webpage installed.

How can I do to grant access to my webapp for the user who has already payed for my this virtual product (access/license).

I have maded a login in PHP, is there a way to check in the WooCommerce database and use the same user and password that the client use to pay for the product? Or is there another simple way?

I'm new at wordpress and woocommerce, so please forgive that and my horrible way to write english.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The user should have it in their order history, if it’s a downloadable product they should be able to log in and download it again.

Comment: it's not downloadable but it's virtual. I want to sell the access to that site, I want to know where is stored the "flag" that demonstrate that the user has already payed for the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe insted look for this status better is use hooks and filters which Woocommerce offers?
From my expirience it's short way to achieve what you want.
Here is example of using it: [LINK](http://squelchdesign.com/web-design-newbury/woocommerce-detecting-order-complete-on-order-completion/).
Take hooks which is responsible for status: completed and than add action to it.

[Woocommerce Memberships](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) - allow you to combine product with permission: if user buy product which would be binded to product he recieves the access to api.

I hope that will help you.

**EDIT:**

```
$sales = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} as posts
            WHERE   posts.post_type     = 'shop_order'
            AND     posts.post_status   IN ( '" . implode( "','", array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold' ) ) . "' )
        " );
```

It's query to database which search for all ordres marked as completed and proccesing.
MySQL query to select IDs of orders with status:completed

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type="shop_order" AND wp_posts.post_status="wc-completed";
```

**EDIT 2**

And also another informations are stored in wp_comments. Inside *wp_comments* are four important columns: *comment_post_ID, comment_content, comment_type* and *user_id*

comment_post_ID = ID from wp_posts

comment_content have information about transaction, which should be recognized by your program.

Comment: Thanks. It seems interesting, I will check it up :)

Comment: Does not work in my case, because my webapp is not a Wordpress page, is an "external" webapp that I made from scratch :(